# Web page stripped away from "layout" after adding paging through "PagedList.Mvc"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout

I wanted to add paging to my website so I installed the "PagedList.Mvc" 
then I made some changes to model like for example changing the type from IEnumerable to IPagedList :

```
 public IPagedList <Product> Products.
```

but I don't think changing model property has anything to do with the problem of layout disappearance.

And in controller part, I just added some properties to send through ViewModel to "Index" page, which I don't think has anything to do with the main problem.

i also added some `<p> and <div>` elements to the "Index" page which i don't think it has anything to do with layout problem since its universal to all pages.

I didn't touch the _layout.cshtml page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>.
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data- 
 toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area 
   = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Shop by Category", "Index", 
    "Categories")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("View All Our Products", "Index", 
    "Products")</li>
            </ul>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Products", FormMethod.Get, new  
    @class = "navbar-form navbar-left"}))
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.TextBox("Search",null,new {@class="form- 
    control",@placeholder="Search Products"})
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            }
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
    </footer>
    </div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

the layout also is mentioned in _ViewStart.cshtml

```
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

but at the end what could be the reason that index page is looking like this, stripped away from menu, links, search box ...
[image]

i'm sure the link between "_layout page" and "views" is broken , but which factors beside  @RenderBody( which already is there) are involved, I don't know.

btw. in the controller, I removed all viewbag and I'm using ViewModel , could it be a reason?

Comment: Not sure but maybe you update bootstrap to version 4. If so you will have to modify your layout with the appropriate html code. Does appear in your html code ?

Comment: what exactly is appropriate HTML code? I had no problem with layout even after updating bootstrap to version 4.1.3, it just happened after implementing paging which I have no idea how could possibly lead to corrupted layout